# About to create my own webshop? Pros and cons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks, e-commerce, webshop

I want to build an e-commerce application with a bunch of features, as multi-language and currency support and some social interaction between the users (it is a fashion store).

I am doing this basically for learning purposes, but also with the hope of earn a little money with it afterwards.

My question is, do you think with all the solutions out there, it is still worth to start from scratch? Which are the pros and cons, and which frameworks do you suggest?

I tend to use ruby on rails, but I know there are also Java and PHP based solutions, so I wonder about the pros and cons of them here as well...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only thing I know is - to make an e-commerce site profitable is a hectic mission, but good luck anyway! (Good way of learning to code etc!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make money selling it to non-developer clients for sure. But if you are trying to make a business of an e-commerce platform you will find rough open source competition.

Check out these options:

PHP:

- [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/)
- [OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/)
- [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)

Rails:

- [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/)

In my case I prepared a web-shop application out of one of the open source ones.

Now for learning it is a good experience start from scratch but it will be difficult to make money of it as a platform unless you do it open source and get paid in advertisement

Comment: which open source shop did you modify and how did it go?

Comment: I modified OS Commerce a couple of years ago and this year I used OpenCart and made some minor modifications. Went very well, each has a lot of plugins you can learn from too.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never learn more than when you build an app that does something you want to do for yourself. If your goal is to learn, go for it.

That said, if your goal is to make money selling stuff, you probably should skip ahead to selling -- use an existing platform like Shopify or Spree and start worrying about what you're going to sell and who is going to buy it. That's a totally different challenge from software development.

Good luck either way.

Comment: yes, my aim is the software development, but I do the shop for a friend which is kind of waiting and polling me for results ;)